# Ngx progress bar deprecated BrowserXhr

Tags: angular

I'm seeing that BrowserXhr is depreciated in the following example:

```
{ provide: BrowserXhr, useClass: NgProgressBrowserXhr }
```

However, when I look at the docs, it redirects to the main httpclient page that doesn't seem to have an equivalent provider example, what has it been replaced with?

Answer (score 0):

in my application here (angular 5) i've imported **NgProgressHttpModule** and progressbar works great for http calls, you can import NgProgressRouterModule for router too

**app.module.ts**

```
  import { NgProgressModule } from '@ngx-progressbar/core';
  import { NgProgressHttpModule } from '@ngx-progressbar/http';
  import { NgProgressRouterModule } from '@ngx-progressbar/router';

  ...
  imports: [
     ...
    HttpClientModule,
    NgProgressModule.forRoot(),
    NgProgressRouterModule,
    NgProgressHttpModule
     ...]
```

you have to add them, here is the content of **package.json**

```
 ...
 "@ngx-progressbar/core": "^4.1.1",
 "@ngx-progressbar/http": "^4.1.1",
 "@ngx-progressbar/router": "^4.1.1",
```

Comment: Looks like the last ngx progress bar commit was a year ago or so from today... I wound up switching to ngx-loading-bar, which worked out of the box, thanks anyways...

Comment: well, turns out that the ngx-progressbar documentation and latest changes won't work easily with httpclient...so i switched too to ngx-loading-bar and solved everything within 5 mins (actually with their old @ngx-progressbar/http-client I managed to make it work but it throw a warning as that library should be not used anymore)